# How to extract text from merged pdf files?

Tags: python, pypdf

I wrote some code to merge a bunch of pdf files that were located in a directory and extract text, however, the code doesn't work.

```
#Merge all pdf files in the parent directory.
merger =  PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
for file in [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]: merger.append(open(file, 'rb'))

#Now extract text from the merged object.
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(merger)
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
    #For each page, get corpus of text.
    for line in page.extractText().splitlines(): corpus += line
```

The following error occurs `AttributeError: 'PdfFileMerger' object has no attribute 'seek'`

I do not wish to output the merged file and then process it - that would be slow and error-prone. How do I use the merged object directly into `PdfFileReader`?

Answer (score 0):

You could "output" the merged file to an IO object in memory, without writing to disk, and then process that pseudo file. Also, your loop uses `open` on many files that you don't later `close`, that's very bad practice and could lead to problems.

```
from StringIO import StringIO # import for IO objects

#Merge all pdf files in the parent directory.
merger =  PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
for file in [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f: # this will also close the file once it's done
        merger.append(f)


#Merge the files and "output" to an IO object instead of a file
tmp = StringIO()
merger.write(tmp)

#Now extract text from the merged object.
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(tmp)
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
    #For each page, get corpus of text.
    for line in page.extractText().splitlines(): corpus += line
```